# Webservice dynamic invoke + get raw data

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, response, raw-data

I use the following code to invoke a webservice from `wsdl` dynamically, which is working perfectly:([see docs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376168/Csharp-Dynamic-Web-Service-Invoker))

Now I want to have the raw data from the response. I found the following:
([Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension%28VS.85%29.aspx.))

But to use that example I need a place to add the method attribute of the extension. Because I invoke the `webservice` method through reflection, I don't have the method definition in my code.

On the previous `webpage` they are talking about creating a `soapextension` to capture the raw messages.
But where do I need to apply the extension in the first code, to have a dynamic webservice invoker with the possibility to request the raw data?

Comment: what your means from `raw data`? binary data(image,blob,etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to convert my code to use WCF instead of the legacy webservice support in C#.
It's also possible to create a class with methods defined in the WSDL file. This allows me to invoke the webservice dynamically like I already did. On the following site I found some example code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx

To get the raw data the only thing I needed to do was adding a behaviour to the endpoint of the service. I learned how to do that on the following page: http://mbsguru.blogspot.be/2012/11/capturing-and-using-raw-soap-messages.html